# What does EuclideanHash in Location Sensitive Hash mean?

Tags: hash, euclidean-distance, trigonometry

I find that `Location Sensitive Hash` support `EuclideanHash` `CosineHash` and some other hash according to the repository in github: [lsh families](https://github.com/JorenSix/TarsosLSH/tree/master/src/be/tarsos/lsh/families). Anyway, `CosineHash` is easy to understand:

```
double result = vector.dot(randomProjection);
return result > 0 ? 1 : 0;
```

But then `EuclideanHash` is hard to understand:

```
double hashValue = (vector.dot(randomProjection)+offset)/Double.valueOf(w); // offset = rand.nextInt(w)
return (int) Math.round(hashValue);
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally Euclidean hash in lsh mean that hash function that map a data (vector) in nearby position in Euclidean space to an integer.

One way to do this is by generating random line, and dividing the line into segments where a segment represent a hash number. Then, hash can be obtained by projecting the data vector to this line and observing which segment it falls to.

The function you asked seems to be using similar approach but using dot product instead of projection